# При тестирование на эмуляторе андроид, смс перехватывается и приходит на другой эмулятор

Tags: android, java

Но при тестировании на реальном устройстве не реагирует, при приходе смс на  апарат не отправляет смс на заданные номер,

Ясность понемногу приходит, дело в том, что я тестил на эмуляторах версии 2.3.3, а теперь при установки моей программы на эмулятор версии 4.3 она перестала работать даже в эмуляторе, какие будут мысли.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала указать параметр `sentIntent` при вызове и проверить `resultCode` для приходящего `Intent`'а в `BroadcastReceiver`'е.

Comment: Например [так][1].

  [1]: http://pastebin.com/7Psuzhsy

Comment: Ты уж конечно не обессудь, но в новом проекте у меня красным подчёркиваются getApplicationContext() и registerReceiver и нехрена не идет. Не сочти за наглость может ты отправишь мне рабочий код. При поступлении на телефон смс он должен отправлять свое смс на другой номер. Или может ссылку дашь где это реализовано. А то делал неделю это проект тестил на эмуляторе, а когда дело дошло до реального телефона все накрылось. В долгу не останусь.

Comment: Адаптировал для работы из `BroadcastReceiver`'а. [Тык][1].

  [1]: http://pastebin.com/xdYk2mjc

Comment: 1) Покажите декларацию ресивера в манифесте. 
2) Для какой версии Android'а пишете? 

Способ перехвата СМС зависит от этих 2-х обстоятельств.

Comment: Minimum Required SDK - 2.2
Target SDK - 2.3.3
Compile With - 4.3


    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

Пишу я как понимаю для версии от 2.3.3 и выше, но на версии 4.3 не работает. Все не получилось вставить символов не хватает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@FFFNikolay](/users/20131/fffnikolay) научитесь сначала правильно декларировать `BroadcastReceiver` - погуглите что ли и только потом задавайте 4 вопроса практически на одну и ту же тему.